# Split on newline-delimited textarea.value returns array of line indices

Tags: javascript, html, json, string, split

I have a JSON data set that's being deserialized and written into a textarea input in the form:

```
{
"key1": "",
"key2": "0",
"key3": "",
"key4": "0"
}
```

Using the following for loop:

```
for (var key in jsonObj.myData) {
    textarea.value += key + ": " + jsonObj.myData[key] + "\n";
}
```

The text appears correctly in the textarea after this operation. Later, I serialize this data using the following for loop:

```
console.log(textarea.value); // Shows text with line breaks as expected
for (var line in textarea.value.split("\n")) {
    console.log(line); // Shows only incrementing number
    var keyval = line.split(": ");
    json += "\"" + keyval[0] + "\": \"" + (keyval[1] || "") + "\",";
}
```

This results in serialized data which looks like this:

```
{
"0": "",
"1": "",
"2": "",
"3": ""
}
```

I would expect that splitting on "\n" would return an array of "key: value" strings as they were entered into the textarea, not (I assume) the index of the line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any difference if you use: `textarea.value.replace(/\r/g, "").split(/\n/)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for-in` loop is iterating over the keys of the array, which are indices, returned by `textarea.value.split("\n")`, not over the elements themselves.

```
var lines = textarea.value.split("\n");
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  // expected "key: value" string
  console.log(lines[i]);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an important distinction between for-in and foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Serializing js objects can be done in much simplier way.

Use `JSON.stringify(<object>)` to turn objects into JSON strings.
Use `JSON.parse(<string>)` to turn JSON strings into objects.